# SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN error while using Heroku Cli

Tags: heroku

I'm try to use Heroku CLI.

But when I want to do some commamd like:

heroku login, heroku log, etc.

The below error will show

```
SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

How can I sovled it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue however this helped me:

Verify your proxy export

```
export NO_PROXY='localhost,localnets, <company proxy IP settings>
```

Then verifying my companies `.pem` file stored in my user directory:

```
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=~/.ssh/bc.pem
```

(or wherever you store it.)

Then try

```
heroku login
```

Answer (score 0):

Its moreover related to security and firewall settings over machine and network.

If you are in secure network, try to connect over proxies / public network, then you can able to run heroku commands.

Or manually acquire SSL/TLS certificate on machine. Kindly refer to [this link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/acquiring-an-ssl-certificate)